# What is the official policy on identifying yourself as a team member for a product?

Tags: support, spam

I'm being told [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/how-do-i-get-my-data-out-of-trello/20891#20891) that I don't need to identify myself every time I answer a question about a product I work on, that I should just add the info into my bio.  I have done this.

This seems important enough to have a documented policy and a standard method of disclaiming, but I can't find that documented anywhere. A comment on a post from a high-rep user is nice, but not quite definitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding your relationship to a particular product or company should be added to your bio.

From this section of the [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)

> **Can I use a signature or tagline?**
>
> Please *don’t* use signatures or taglines in your posts, or they will
>   be removed.
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card,
>
> [image: User card hover]
>
> which links directly back to your [user page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/9179/rich-armstrong).
>
> Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your
>   interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

As long as you are answering question, which of course you are, and not just spamming for business then all is well.

It worth pointing out the people don't have to click through to see this details. Just by hovering over your picture will expand out to reveal your details.

Comment: This should be considered as a partial answer. See this other [answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4963/88163).

Answer (score 3):

The guidance is clear:

> [you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 2):

Not everyone has the 1,000 reputation needed to show the user card, so if you can mention your affiliation organically then that's better than just tagging on your affiliation like a signature.

It might be OK to mention it in the first few answers you give and then leave it out subsequently (and even go back and edit it out of the early answers) as people get used to you answering.

Comment: While this will work for the regular users who recognize names, "people get used to you answering" will not really occur for new askers and people who find the question from a search engine. "Mention the affiliation organically" sounds better.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - Good point there.

Comment: This should be considered as a partial answer. See this other [answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4963/88163).

Answer (score 0):

This is a clarification of previous answers.

A lot of things have changed since this question was posted.

[Expected Behavior](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) prohibits the use of signatures, however, if in your posts includes information about external content or products that you are directly or indireclty professionaly related (you have benefits in exchange of posting content), you should disclouse your affiliation.

This help article points to [How to not be a spammer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

If you got a badge for your participation as voluntary in a community or project and get occasional swag and event invitations but not get economical or material compesations / rewards like the Google Product Expert Program, you don't have to disclousure your affiliation. But if you work for a company and you answer questions about products of that company, even in your free time, then you should disclose your affiliation.

## Related

- [Do I need to disclose my affiliation on non-promotional, technical answers on my project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204665/289691)